# TableView with dynamically height

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, height

I'm programming on objective-c. I have a viewController with tableView. I would like that my tableView has a dynamically height like on a picture below (Tweetbot). How can I make it?

[image]

Comment: Dynamically heiht means ? elaborate

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 use this method and see matches your solution or not ?

Comment: @ArpitParekh this method for a row height. I'd like dynamically height for my tableview. For example, if I have a 2 rows (height = 44 for each row) I'd like that my table was height 88, not a 480 (or 460 it depends on bars on the top)

Comment: If this question is resolved, either accept an answer or answer it yourself with information on how you resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However its not clear that this table is "short" - it may be that it has a transparent background and only two cells. In any case, to make a short table you would create a UIViewController class with a normal view (ie a UIView). Create a UIImageView and add the image to it (assuming you want a big image), and add that to the view (you could do this in IB). Then create a UITableView of the desired height, and add that too to the UIIView's subviews. Now you have a container view (self.view) with two subviews, the table being the last (so its on top).

Answer (score 1):

Most likly tweetbot doesn't add a `UITableView` upon a `UIViewController`. They most likely use the `UITableViewController` from scratch, giving it a background and (in this case) showing only two cells with a custom height. That is also the "way-2-go" when using the Table View.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and use if condition or switch case in this method.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row ==2) {
        return 89;//write your image view's height here.
    }
    return 44;
}
```